# Prove that $Z[i]/(5)$ is not a field. Check proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is my work, I am self learning basic algebra.
Firstly, by definition:
$Z[i]/(5)= \{a+bi + (5): a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where (5) is the principal ideal generated by 5. Let I=(5).
Now we claim the coset $2+i+I$ has no inverse. Here's my justification.
If $2+i+ I$ had an inverse, then there would be $a+bi$ such that
$(2+i)I (a+bi) I= 1 + I$, in other words we would have $(2+i)(a+bi) -1 \in I$ or equivalently $(2+i)(a+bi)-1= 5(c+di)$ for some $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $2a-b + (2b+a) i -1= 5c+5di$ and so matching real and imaginary parts, we have $2a-b-1= 5c$ and $2b+a=5d$ and so $b= 2a-5c-1$ which we subtitute into $2b+a=5d$ to get $2(2a-5c-1)+a= 5d$ which implies $5(a-d-2c)=2$. But 5 does not divide 2, contradiction.

Is this correct or have I overlooked something? Thanks.

Comment: That's a fine proof, though it's probably easier to just note that $(2+i)(2-i) = 5$, so $\mathbb{Z}[i]/5\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has zero divisors.

Comment: You could have just shown that $\langle5\rangle$ is not a maximal ideal, because $\langle5\rangle\subsetneq\langle5,i\rangle\subsetneq\Bbb{Z}[i]$

Comment: Thanks Alex, that is indeed much simpler! Then is it true for any number 
 k which is the sum of two squares, $Z[i]/(k)$ is not a field by the same argument?

Comment: Thanks Abishanka! Is it easy to show the last inclusion?

Comment: @PaulDavis: yep! Also, I don't think Abishanka's argument is quite right, since $i$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (and so $\langle 5, i \rangle$ is the whole ring). Furthermore, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a principal ideal domain, so any ideal will have a single generator. You can patch the argument by analogously observing that $\langle 5 \rangle$ is properly contained in (say) $\langle 2 + i \rangle$, which is not the whole ring, since the only units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are $\pm 1, \pm i$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z[i]/(5) \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1,5) \cong \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x+2)(x+3) \cong \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x+2) \times \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x+3) \cong \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_5 $

Comment: Why  $\mathbb Z_5[x]/(x+2)(x+3) \cong \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x+2) \times \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x+3)$ chinesse theorem right?

Comment: @eraldcoil. right.